# Adding Authorization to Header

Tags: angular6, angular-http-interceptors, xtrareport

i'm using Angular 6 and DevExpress Xtra-report module. I want to added Authorization in header.Well i'm using  HttpInterceptor to add Authorization  and its working good with all my others modules except my xtra-report module so i tried to pass the authorization using jquery inside my module (as shown bellow ) which is not working and i'm not really comfortable with it.
I'm getting the Token inside userId.

```
const userId = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true,
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userId}`,
    },
    complete: function (result) {
        // console.log('complete');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, erreur) {
        // console.log('error');
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        console.log(`beforeSend beforeSend beforeSend beforeSend beforeSend beforeSend + ${userId}`);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.Authorization = `Bearer ${userId}`;
    }
});
```

I dont know why HttpInterceptor work with all my module except xtra-report module, maybe cause i'm charging it lazy or i dont know , any help would be appreciated, tell me in case of additional informations  from my side. 
Thank you

Comment: Usually when you work with C# in ASP.NET as your backend, you should take care about authentication/authorization and its mechanisms when using Authorize attribute on your controllers. Verify what's happening in your Chrome's developer console to detect the error, if it comes from backend or it is about your front end (usually the devexpress-reporting has the document preview control and it can be changed with some variables)

Comment: I solved this issue by adding headers : { } and pass Authorization inside it instead of passing it inside xhrFields

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by adding headers with Authorization inside it , so it becomes like this :

```html
const userId = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true,
    type: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true,
     },
     headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userId}`,
     },
    complete: function (result) {
        // console.log('complete');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, erreur) {
        // console.log('error');
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        console.log(`beforeSend beforeSend beforeSend beforeSend beforeSend beforeSend + ${userId}`);
      xhr.withCredentials = true;
      xhr.Authorization = `Bearer ${userId}`;
    }
});
```

Hopefully this could help someone one day